# How to permanently get IP address

Tags: android, webserver

I have a Web Server app running on port **3000**, now when I get my IP address from **Settings** > **About Phone**, here it shows my ip address.

When I type that IP address in browser with port 3000, it shows the **index of /** its amazing, but the problem is that when I reconnect my phone to internet it gets changed.

Does anyone knows how to get that IP permanently, or access my phone from the internet?

Comment: What version of android are you running?

Comment: Android Lollipop 5.1.1 (Stock)

Comment: do you know how to do that..

Comment: Yep, I am typing my answer now.

Comment: So i access my web server over carrier's network by typing this 10.1.x.x:3000 in browser..

Comment: Sadly this question is off-topic for this site. It is a good fit for our sister site [android.se]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do to two things.

**First Step**

Set your static IP address

1. Open Settings
2. Go to the Wi-Fi settings
3. You will see a list of networks tap and hold your network.
4. Tap edit (or modify network)
5. Tap advanced
6. You can now see the settings related to your IP address, Gateway, and DNS set these as you would like them.
7. Confirm your settings by trying to access google.com
8. Write down the IP address you gave your phone

**Second Step**

Go to your router and create an exception for the web servers port / ip address. Note that this differs depending on your router. See the manufactures website or the included manual for how to do this.

**Things To Note**

1. This will only work on the network you configure it for
2. You are accepting liability for the devices security. Opening a device especially an Android phone to the Internet is inherently dangerous.
3. Resetting the phone or an operating system update my change these settings.
4. This is only possible on an Wifi or Ethernet internet connection. NOT a cellular 2G / 3G / 4G / 4G LTE connection.
5. Even if you could get a static IP you would still most likly be in TOS or EULA violation, at least with all the major carriers it is against their TOS to use the connection for hosting a server. You could end up with a terminated phone plan if you try to bypass the block. If you wish to do this I would highly recommend talking to them first.
6. The IP address reported by your phone in the Settings > About Phone > Status is your Wifi or Ethernet. I added a picture. Sorry about the bad blocking out not a fan of the new Paint in Windows 10 Insider.
   [image: Image of Menu]

That's it. Good luck!

Sources :

1. My Android 5.1.1 Phone
2. http://www.speedguide.net/ip/10.1.166.177

Comment: Hey, I am not having WiFi Connection.

Comment: Wait is this an Android phone?

Comment: @user683016, if you mean that this is on a carrier's network, you are out of luck.

Comment: Is their anything else that redirect traffic to my IP

Comment: Sorry this only works on WiFi. @RonMaupin is right you have no control over your carriers network.

Comment: @user683016 How is your phone connecting to the internet? As far as I knew carriers blocked incoming connections to your phones IP. And if your not on cellular then your either Wifi, Ethernet, or Bluetooth.

Comment: I am using my sim network (4G)

Comment: Who is your carrier?

Comment: If you wont belive go through this link http://10.1.166.177:3000/

Comment: this ip is valid till my connection is established to internet. when i reconnect to internet it get changed..

Comment: Goto that link you will see **hello world** written their, is it??

Comment: I was not able to connect, I suspect that you are connected to Wifi. Reason being that this is an IANA reserved private subnet no cell carrier has this IP subnet (or any other ISP for that matter). http://www.speedguide.net/ip/10.1.166.177

Comment: The fine print in your phone contract forbids you from running a server. The carriers often have special business contracts that will allow for this, but you end up paying for both incoming and outgoing traffic.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for mentioning the point. Were you able to connect? Based on the IANA reservation of certain subnets I doubt that the IP given is public but I can not verify this for 100%

Comment: I didn't even try to connect because it is a private address. Even if it was a public address, I don't want to connect to an unknown, possibly malicious, site.

Comment: Some carriers use CGN, and use the private address ranges instead of the preferred Shared Address Space of `100.64.0.0/10`, which is not public address space anyway. The carrier could be doing NAT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Dynamic DNS service](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dynamic%20dns) like NoIP or DynDNS.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Register on one of their's site, then input the login data to one of apps in Google Play.

Comment: oh yeh, i have downloaded Dynamic DNC Client. what to do now.

Comment: Register with them.

Comment: This will only work if the carrier is not using NAT, and it appears that it is, based on the IP address. A customer has no way to have the carrier forward a port through its NAT.

Comment: @RonMaupin You are probably right.